Pritunl VPN on Public and Office Networks
Description
I have a Pritunl VPN server configured on an Azure virtual machine within a VNet hub. When connecting to the VPN from home networks, everything works correctly: I can access both internal IPs on Azure and public Internet. However, when I try to connect from the office network or a public network (like in a bar), I cannot access either internal IPs or the public Internet.
Technical Details
Internal DNS Resolver
The internal Azure DNS resolver is configured as 10.1.2.5.
Configurations Done:
The Azure DNS resolver 10.1.2.5 is set as the DNS server in the Pritunl server settings.
I tried enabling the "No Restrict Routing" option, which allows access to the public Internet, but internal IPs still time out.
Observations:
This issue only occurs on the office network and public networks. On home networks, both internal and external access works perfectly.
When connected to problematic networks, nslookup for internal and external domains returns results, indicating DNS resolution is working.
Standard troubleshooting like checking firewall settings, DNS settings, and VPN configuration have been performed without resolving the issue.
Ping and NSLookup Results:
Ping to 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=114 time=15.214 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=11.694 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=15.275 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=15.667 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=114 time=12.372 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=114 time=15.422 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.694/14.274/15.667/1.603 ms

NSLookup for google.com using internal DNS resolver:
Server:     10.1.2.5
Address:    10.1.2.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.39.110

Summary of the Issue:
When connected to the VPN from office or public networks:

Cannot access internal IPs. The web browser is timing out
Cannot access public Internet. The web browser is timing out
Pinging the internal Azure DNS resolver (10.1.2.5) results in successful DNS resolution, but connectivity fails.
Enabling "No Restrict Routing" allows public Internet access but not internal IPs.

How I can configure the VPN network to avoid this problem?
